# Code not working in PHP if else statement

Tags: php

I am trying to create a nav bar where if you are a guest it displays a lock icon and 'Log in' and when you are logged in it displays a lock icon and 'Logout'.
Here is the code for my header:

```
    <section class="top-bar-section">
  <ul class="left">
    <li><a href="/"><img src="images/icons/home_icon.png"> Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="page_about_1.html"><img src="images/icons/about_icon.png"> About</a></li>
    <li><a href="page_showcase_2.html"><img src="images/icons/pages_icon.png"> Showcase</a></li>
    <li><a href="page_videos_5.html"><img src="images/icons/videos_icon.png"> Videos</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="right">
      <?php
        if (!empty($UserName))
        {
        echo <li><a href="admin/"><img src="../images/icons/login_icon.png"> Log in</a></li>;
        }
        else
        {
        echo <li><a href="<?php echo $logoutAction ?>"><img src="../images/icons/login_icon.png"> Logout</a></li>;
        }
      ?>
  </ul>
</section>
```

the section I am working on is under `<ul class="right">`

and the error I am getting when testing the webpage is

> `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in
>   C:\wamp\www...\header.php on line 16

PS: Line 16 is where the first 'echo' is

HELP! Please :) Thanks

Comment: `echo` works with string expressions, so you must quote your HTML if you wish to print it.

Comment: You should echo string in a `quotes`. Read [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it can easily be found in [the manual entry for `echo()`](http://php.net/echo).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put the string in the `echo` statement in quotes (I'd suggest single-quotes, since you've got doubles in the text).

Comment: thank you, this worked. I was using double quotes before but by using a single one it works.

Answer (score 2):

try like this you are missing quote on echo

```
if (!empty($UserName)) {
        echo '<li><a href="admin/"><img src="../images/icons/login_icon.png"> Log in</a></li>';
}
else {
        echo '<li><a href="'.$logoutAction .'"><img src="../images/icons/login_icon.png"> Logout</a></li>';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The echo requires string like this

```
echo "Hello World";
```

So your echo statements must be like this:

```
echo '<li><a href="admin/"><img src="../images/icons/login_icon.png"> Log in</a></li>';
echo '<li><a href="'.$logoutAction.'"><img src="../images/icons/login_icon.png"> Logout</a></li>';
```

If you want to use double quotes you should escape quotes that are in the string

```
echo "\""; /* would echo " */
```